# How to interpret the square root of inner product over an arbitrary field?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In an inner product space, the norm $\|x\| = \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$ is induced. I realise I have almost always dealt with either real or complex numbers, so took the square root for granted.

Reading the Inner Product entry on
Wolfram (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html), it says "**A vector space together with an inner product on it is called an inner product space. This definition also applies to an abstract vector space over any field.**" This was said after introducing the axioms in the context of a space over $\mathbb{R}$.

I am confused because I do not know how to interpret the square root in an arbitrary field. I assume the obvious way would be to define it to be the element $a \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $a^2 = \langle x,x\rangle$. But the issue I am having is how we even know whether such an element exists in the field? Is this a standard result from ring theory?

My understanding has always been that inner product spaces (and normed spaces) are **only** defined over either the real or complex numbers. How do you construct them (or something equivalent) over some arbitrary field?

Comment: You can define them over the algebraic closure of the rational numbers. But not over an arbitrary field (for example, it is impossible to even define an inner product over a finite field). In general, in order to define an inner product, your field needs to be ordered. On the other hand, there are ways to define a norm on a vector space that do not rely on an inner product (for example, the Hamming distance).

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks for this, though I am still a little confused. Suppose we use some ordered field, how does this work with the square root? Are we guaranteed its existence?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Also another thing I have just thought of, is how we would interpret the conjugate symmetry axiom in an arbitrary ordered field? I believe this axiom is what ensures $\langle x, x\rangle$ is a real number. I believe this is also essential since the norm is always a map $V \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No, not at all. The wikipedia page for Inner Product Space gives a good explanation for this (under "Alternate Definitions, notation, and remarks"): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

Comment: @masiewpao Not every field contains square roots. For example, in $\mathbb{Q}$ the number $2$ has no square roots. Now, you can define an inner product over $\mathbb{Q}$, but it will not give you a norm. In general, it is hard to define an interesting inner product over a field which is not $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: But you can have proper subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$, the you would take the conjugate to be the normal complex conjugate. You may or may not have every element having a square root ("quadratically closed").

Comment: But the theory of Bilinear Forms, Sesquilinear Forms, and Quadratic Forms is very interesting are interesting over all sorts of fields.

Comment: @masiewpao As for conjugation, there is no such term over an arbitrary field. However, inner products can be defined on modules over $C^*$-algebras, if you know what it is. (because involution of a $C^*$-algebra is indeed a generalization of complex conjugation)

Comment: @Mark Ah OK, I didn't actually know that was possible!

Comment: @MorganRodgers Thanks for the responses, I'm not very familiar with everything so I'm going through it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim doesn't make sense. On vector spaces $V$ over arbitrary field $k$ we have bilinear forms $b(x,y)$. When $k=\Bbb{C}$ we also look at sesquilinear forms, which means that the second argument is linear after applying an automorphism $\sigma$ of the field (the complex conjugaison). But then we can consider $V$ as a $k^\sigma$ vector space to make it linear, so assume that $b$ is truly linear.

$q(x) = b(x,x)$ is a quadratic form.

A first desirable property is that $b(x,y)=b(y,x)$ (when $char(k)\ne 2$ there is a one-to-one correspondence between quadratic forms and symmetric bilinear forms).

A second one is that $q(x)=0$ iff $x=0$. In that case $q$ is said anisotropic.

When $k$ is an ordered field there is a 3rd one: that $\forall x,q(x)\ge 0$. With the previous ones this is the definition of "$b$ is an inner product". When it is the case then $\|x\|=\sqrt{q(x)}$ is some kind of norm (when $k$ is not a subfield of $\Bbb{R}$ then $\|x\|$ is not real valued so this is a bit different). Do you think we always have $\|x+y\| \le \|x\|+\|y\|$ ?

$\sqrt{q(x)}$ is an element of the algebraic extension of $k$ obtained by adding all the square roots of elements $\ge 0$, it is ordered too, through $\sqrt{a}\ge \sqrt{b}$ iff $a\ge b$, then applying the law of orders.

Note that real valued norms exist other any fields, for example $\|x\| = 0$ if $x_1=x_2=0$ and $=1$ otherwise is a real-valued norm over $k^2$ for any field, a norm for the trivial absolute value  $|a|_{tr}= 0$ if $a=0$ and $=1$ otherwise, such that $\|ax\|=|a|_{tr} \|x\|$.

Answer (score -1):

You do not have a norm defined for an arbitrary inner product space. For instance,  $\langle x, y\rangle = x_1 y_1 - x_2 y_2$ is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The norm will be defined on euclidian spaces or hermitian spaces. There are extra conditions ( positivity) required.

Comment: The formula you give is **not** an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$; to see this, notice that  $\langle \begin{bmatrix} 1\\2 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1\\2 \end{bmatrix}\rangle < 0$. Also, we can define a norm from any (actual) inner product on $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers:  Well, according to this site https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inner+product+space it is.  Perhaps it's a more general definition

Comment: That is very much a nonstandard definition. Compare to that found on Wikipedia, or given in books by Axler, or Lang (as "scalar product").